# Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapinghub

I have a spider for LinkedIn. It is working fine on my local machine but when I deploy on Scrapinghub I got error:

```
Error downloading <GET https://www.linkedin.com/>: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
```

The complete log of Scrapinghub is:

```
0:  2018-08-30 12:58:34 INFO    Log opened.
1:  2018-08-30 12:58:34 INFO    [scrapy.log] Scrapy 1.0.5 started
2:  2018-08-30 12:58:34 INFO    [scrapy.utils.log] Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: facebook_stats)
3:  2018-08-30 12:58:34 INFO    [scrapy.utils.log] Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
4:  2018-08-30 12:58:34 INFO    [scrapy.utils.log] Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'facebook_stats.spiders', 'STATS_CLASS': 'sh_scrapy.stats.HubStorageStatsCollector', 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['facebook_stats.spiders'], 'RETRY_TIMES': 10, 'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408], 'BOT_NAME': 'facebook_stats', 'MEMUSAGE_LIMIT_MB': 950, 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1, 'TELNETCONSOLE_HOST': '0.0.0.0', 'LOG_FILE': 'scrapy.log', 'MEMUSAGE_ENABLED': True, 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.7'}
5:  2018-08-30 12:58:34 INFO    [scrapy.log] HubStorage: writing items to https://storage.scrapinghub.com/items/341545/3/9
6:  2018-08-30 12:58:34 INFO    [scrapy.middleware] Enabled extensions: CoreStats, TelnetConsole, MemoryUsage, LogStats, StackTraceDump, CloseSpider, SpiderState, AutoThrottle, HubstorageExtension
7:  2018-08-30 12:58:35 INFO    [scrapy.middleware] Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
8:  2018-08-30 12:58:35 INFO    [scrapy.middleware] Enabled spider middlewares: HubstorageMiddleware, HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
9:  2018-08-30 12:58:35 INFO    [scrapy.middleware] Enabled item pipelines: CreditCardsPipeline
10: 2018-08-30 12:58:35 INFO    [scrapy.core.engine] Spider opened
11: 2018-08-30 12:58:36 INFO    [scrapy.extensions.logstats] Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
12: 2018-08-30 12:58:36 INFO    TelnetConsole starting on 6023
13: 2018-08-30 12:59:32 ERROR   [scrapy.core.scraper] Error downloading <GET https://www.linkedin.com/>: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
14: 2018-08-30 12:59:32 INFO    [scrapy.core.engine] Closing spider (finished)
15: 2018-08-30 12:59:33 INFO    [scrapy.statscollectors] Dumping Scrapy stats: More
16: 2018-08-30 12:59:34 INFO    [scrapy.core.engine] Spider closed (finished)
17: 2018-08-30 12:59:34 INFO    Main loop terminated.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LinkedIn [prohibits scraping](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/56347/prohibited-software-and-extensions?lang=en):

> ### Prohibited Software and Extensions
>
> LinkedIn is committed to keeping its members' data safe and its website free from fraud and abuse. In order to protect our members’ data and our website, we don't permit the use of any third party software, including "crawlers", bots, browser plug-ins, or browser extensions (also called "add-ons"), that scrapes, modifies the appearance of, or automates activity on LinkedIn’s website. Such tools violate the [User Agreement](https://www.linkedin.com/legal/user-agreement), including, but not limited to, many of the "Don'ts" listed in Section 8.2…

It's reasonable to think that they may actively block connections from Scrapinghub and similar services.

Comment: So there is no way to further scrap pages on Scrapinghub ??

Comment: @OmarRiaz, considering this is against the LinkedIn User Agreement I _strongly_ advise against doing this on Scrapinghub or anywhere else. If you decide to try anyway you will have technical challenges like this one to overcome. It's unlikely that you'll be able to scrape LinkedIn from Scrapinghub no matter what you do.